# Why cv::cuda::remap wrong while cv::remap right?

Tags: opencv, remap

I use `cv::cuda::remap` instead of `cv::remap` to take advantage of CUDA acceleration to speed up video undistortion. Both versions of the program can run normally, but, while the camera matrix, distortion coefficients, map1 and map2 which come from `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap()` are all the same, the undistorted result image of the CPU version `cv::remap` is correct as follow:

[image]

but the CUDA version `cv::cuda::remap` results in a problem:

[image]

The code snippet for the CPU version is as follows:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuMat(m_height, m_width, CV_8UC4, (void *)dpFrame);
cv::Mat mat;
gpuMat.download(mat);
cv::remap(mat, mat, m_map1, m_map2, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
gpuMat.upload(mat);
```

GPU version:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuMat(m_height, m_width, CV_8UC4, (void *)dpFrame);
cv::cuda::remap(gpuMat, gpuMat, m_gpuMap1, m_gpuMap2, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

Among them, `dpFrame` is of type `CUdeviceptr`, `m_map1` and `m_map2` are calculated by `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap`, `m_gpuMap1` and `m_gpuMap2` are of type `cv::cuda::GpuMat` obtained by uploading `m_map1` and `m_map2` to GPU.

`cv::remap` and `cv::cuda::remap` are the same algorithm, why are their results different? I tried both versions of OpenCV 455 and 460, and neither works.

I'm stuck here and don't know how to go forward. Any suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you... expected that to work in-place? I wouldn't even expect that to work in-place on the CPU. this operation can't be performed in-place *in principle*. it has to be an operation from one piece of memory to the other. if anything here made "in-place" "work", it did an implicit copy/allocation.

Comment: NB: remapping _can_ sometimes be done in-place, after examining the map and figuring out which pixels to map in what order, which directly depends on the values in the map and means you can't just iterate over it in arbitrary ways. in some cases interpolation would become tricky too. -- none of that happens in `cv::remap()`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation on the in-place issue. It does matter whether an algorithm can operate in-place. @ChristophRackwitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, I also tried your code and got the similar results. I ended up with getting a correct result after a few tests.

My code simply flips an image with remap. Here is your code result to my input:

## Code

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuMat(m_height, m_width, CV_8UC4, (void *)dpFrame);
cv::cuda::remap(gpuMat, gpuMat, m_gpuMap1, m_gpuMap2, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

## Input

[image]

## Output

[image]

Then I just add a new declaration of `cv::cuda::GpuMat` and put it to output of `resize` function. Here is the code.

```
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuMat(m_height, m_width, CV_8UC4, (void *)dpFrame);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuMat2;
    cv::cuda::remap(gpuMat, gpuMat2, m_gpuMap1, m_gpuMap2, cv::INTER_LINEAR);

    gpuMat2.download(mat);
```

## New Output

[image]

I dont have a clear answer to the question why. Since we deal with gpu, it seems better to define different types for input and output of `resize`

Comment: It is right. Thank you very much. I separate the two parameters, it results correctly. `cv::cuda::GpuMat` has a member method `copyTo`, I use it to make a GpuMat as the source.